# Hashset duplicate values but I dont have custom objects

Tags: java, hashset

I am using jsoup parser to extract my anchor tags and then I am just adding the links to a hash set.
The code is as follows

Posting my entire code. I understand the issue is because I am using toString and the value would change My goal is when I get a bunch of links I want to eliminate links such as http://cse.syr.edu and http://cse.syr.edu/ so that my hashSet contains unique elements. How could I do this

```
for ( Element link : links)
{
        String test=link.attr("abs:href");

        if(!(link.attr("abs:href").contains("http://cse.syr.edu")))
            continue ;
        else if(h.isEmpty()){
            h.add(test);
        }
        else if(h.contains(test) || h.contains(test+"/")) // I now removed (test+"/")
            continue;
        else {

        h.add(test);
```

}

I have updated my question now thanks RJ

Comment: Can you post a sample I/O because AFAIK, a `Set` would do its job properly, unless its made to mess up.

Comment: `HashSet`s can't contain duplicates. check and make sure your keys are correct.

Comment: do `System.out.println(h);` and show the output, it will help to answer this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's probably whitespace in your Strings. HashSet works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about `java.util.HashSet`, the most likely explanation is that your diagnosis of the problem is incorrect. Make sure that the strings in the set are indeed identical (and not subtly different), and that you are not accidentally re-creating or clearing the `HashSet` between adding identical strings.